# How can I truncate a table when mysqld is not running?

Tags: mysql, innodb

One of my mysql tables(innodb/Barracuda, mysql version 5.7) is corrupted, which makes mysqld down. I cannot restart mysqld even setting innodb_force_recovery=5. Setting  innodb_force_recovery=6 can start mysqld successfully but in read-only mode, so I cannot truncate the corrupted table.

Is there a way to truncate a table when mysqld is not running? If I delete the .ibd file directly, it seems to have problem. I want to preserve the table structure but empty the table content.

Comment: What happens if you also delete the .frm file?

Comment: Create a table with the same name and precisely the same structure in another (temporarily created) database. Create the same amount of fake rows in it. Then stop the server and replace (copy) problematic table body with one of new table. Start server in recovery mode. After the starting truncate the table.

Comment: @RickJames I think if I delete the .frm file, the table structure would be lost. I want to preserve the table structure.

Comment: @Akina The mysql server is down so I cannot create another table.

Comment: Or move it aside for the time being.  There may be an issue of creating a table by juggling files -- there certainly will be when you get to 8.0.